# Someone know the ADB command for the "Fix network" button on android 12?

Tags: android, command, adb

sometimes my WiFi disconnects and mobile network dont connects automatically and I must to go to internet settings to push the reset button. I want to automate this using tasker, but I dont found anything about ADB commands related to this button.

[image]